# Python App Engine endpoints_proto_datastore ImportError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, endpoints-proto-datastore

So I have the endpoints_proto_datastore folder at the root of my project and yet I get this error each time I try to run it....

```
File "C:\pythonworkspace\...\endpoints_proto_datastore\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import model
ImportError: cannot import name model
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel